# wxpython passing information, pointers?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to code up an application to help me keep track of my students.  Basically a customized notebook/gradebook.  I hacked something together last summer that worked for this past year, but I need something better.

I'm going to pull each students record from a database, display it on my main page and have elements clickable to open a frame so that I can edit it.  I need to pass information between these two frames and I'm an idiot because I can't seem to figure out how to alter the examples I've come across showing lambdas and same-class information passing.

On my main window I have a StaticText that looks like this

```
self.q1a_lbl = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_MAINWINDOWQ1A_LBL, label=u'87%',
      name=u'q1a_lbl', parent=self.alg_panel, pos=wx.Point(115, 48),
      size=wx.Size(23, 17), style=0)
self.q1a_lbl.SetToolTipString(u'Date \n\nNotes')
self.q1a_lbl.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnQ1a_lblLeftUp)
```

Then I have the function:

```
def OnQ1a_lblLeftUp(self, event):
    import quiz_notes
    quiz_notes.create(self).Show(True)
```

Which works graphically, but I'm not really doing anything other than opening a window when the text is clicked on.  Then I have another Frame with

```
import wx

def create(parent):
return quiz_notes(parent)

[wxID_QUIZ_NOTES, wxID_QUIZ_NOTESCANCEL_BTN, wxID_QUIZ_NOTESDATEPICKERCTRL1, 
 wxID_QUIZ_NOTESENTER_BTN, wxID_QUIZ_NOTESPANEL1, wxID_QUIZ_NOTESTEXTCTRL1, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(6)]

class quiz_notes(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
...and so on
```

I would like to pass at least a couple of variables.  Eventually, when I start integrating the database into it, I would just pass a tuple.  Or a reference to it.  In C I'd just use a pointer. Anyway, make changes and then go back to my main window.  In short, whats the best way to work with data between these two classes?

Comment: "I would like to pass at least a couple of variables. " .. what, from where, to what? What's wrong with passing your arguments to your functions, class?

Comment: Pseudo code:  Class1.function --> tuple_whatever --> Class2.function.modifies tuple --> returns Class1 with tuple changed.

Answer (score 2):

There are not pointers in Python, but there are mutable structures. You can share state between objects by handing the same state-object to multiple instances.

What that state-object should be depends entirely on what you're trying to do (I still have no idea). It could be anything mutable, a module, class, instance, dict or list.

In this example the shared state is a list in a global variable:

```
# a list is mutable
state = 'Hello World'.split()

class Class1:
    def hi(self):
        print ' '.join(state)
        # do something to the shared state
        state[0] = 'Bye'

class Class2:
    def hi(self):
        print ' '.join(state)

x = Class1()
y = Class2()
x.hi()
y.hi()
```

Comment: OK.  I'm not sure why, because I did read a lot of other pages, but this makes sense to me.  I'll be able to run with it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Mike Driscoll's [blog post on using PubSub in wxPython.](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/)

It's using the included PubSub in wxPython - just be aware that it is a [stand-alone library](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/), and the latest version's API is different to the one included in wx (a better API, if I may say so)